# How to define relative dependency with brunch

Tags: javascript, brunch

Brunch allows for specifying the concatentation order in the JS processing via `before` and `after`.

I have the following dependency order:

- some bower components
- a setup file (setup.js)
- more JS files

so basically the setup.js file needs the bower components to be there, but it must be loaded before other JS files.

If I put setup.js in the `before` list, it is included before the bower components.

How can I make sure setup.js gets included right between my bower components/vendor libs and my own JS.

Answer (score 1):

```
before: [
  'bower_components/**/*',
  'setup.js'
]
```

Comment: This does not use the brunch feature of resolving transitive dependencies - it just bakes in all files under bower_components alphabetically.

Comment: That shouldn't be the case. Brunch's implementation of anysort should deal with the problem you're describing by resolving sorting ties with the remaining matchers. If you can provide a reproducible case that proves otherwise, please file an issue.